# How to migrate data to BigQuery (From db2)

Tags: google-bigquery, database-migration

What would be the best ways to migrate data from a db2 database to big query?

Comment: please define `best`

Comment: Easiest 
Quickest
Cheapest 
So far I am thinking of migrating from the db2 database to bigquery within Dbeaver>
but I am sure there must be a better way that doesn't involve using a etl service.